# django extends template

Tags: django

Не получается расширить шаблон `base.html` шаблоном `header.html`

Содержимое  `base.html`

```
<div id="main-container">
  <!-- HEADER -->
  {% block header %}{% endblock %}
  <!-- END HEADER -->
</div>
```

Содержимое  `header.html`

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block header %}
<header id="header">
***
</header>
{% endblock %}
```

На выходе получаю код:

```
<div id="main-container">
  <!-- HEADER -->

  <!-- END HEADER -->
```

Почему не получаться расширить шаблон?
Через `{% include "blog/header.html" %}` - работает, а через  `extends` нет.
Использую Django 1.10.1

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404 (Post, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'blog/base.html', {'post': post})

def header(request):
    return render (request, 'blog/header.html')
```

Comment: Покажите код вьюхи, может вы не тот шаблон указываете. И поправьте скобки в `{% extends "blog/base.html %}`, а то непонятно, у вас опечатка при копипасте или таки в коде.

Comment: Написано всё правильно.

Comment: Добавил код views.py

Comment: Собственно у вас только в последней вьюхе (`def header(request)`) и должен отображаться хидер, в остальных его и не должно быть. Уточните, в какой конкретно из указанных вьюх у вас работает не так.

Comment: Сейчас добавил `def header(request)` во views.py , но блок все равно не выводиться.